# Load page wait a second then download file using Codeigniter v2

Tags: php, codeigniter, download

I have a controller that in nutshell is as follows:

```
public function download($id) {
  $data = array();

  force_download($data['brochure']->location, $data['brochure']->name);  
  $this->renderPage('site/download', $data); // simple method basically same as load->view
}
```

I want the page view and then after a second to force download the file - the current function downloads the file but not the view, can anyone suggest how to get around this?

Comment: Maybe you should do the redirect with javascript a second after the page has loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line the following line from download function

```
force_download($data['brochure']->location, $data['brochure']->name);
```

Write another function

```
public function download_file($id) {
  $data = array();
  force_download($data['brochure']->location, $data['brochure']->name);  
}
```

Now in the download view add the following javascript/jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        downloadFile('<your file location>')
    },1000);
});

function downloadFile(url)
{
    var iframe;
    iframe = document.getElementById("download-container");
    if (iframe === null)
    {
        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  
        iframe.id = "download-container";
        iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
    iframe.src = url;   
}
```

Comment: No problem, Gaz. I'm Vivek BTW ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two actions:

1. To display the download page (`$this->renderPage(...)`).
2. To make the browser download the file (`force_download(...)`).

In the first one, you add some javascript or a meta-tag in the head to redirector to the second action after a second.

The download page will be displayed and then after a second, the download offered.

Comment: Sussed it! Thanks guys (can't get the formatting right?) - oh well hope it helps someone.

    <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout("get_download()", 3000);
    
        function get_download()
        {
            window.location.href = <?php echo $javascript_url ?>;
        }  
    </script>